# Orphelin transaction named 'offline index build' hang forever

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

So I'm having a problem with SQL Server 2008 R2 that I didn't have in SQL Server 2005.

I backuped a database and restored it to SQL Server 2008 R2. It's a standard database of moderate size with some indexes and fulltext indexes.

The problem now is that I have an open transaction that never ends.

When I execute the query:

```
DBCC OPENTRAN;
```

I get as result:
Transaction information for database 'MediaTrunk2005'.

```
Oldest active transaction:
    SPID (server process ID): 34s
    UID (user ID) : -1
    Name          : offline index build
    LSN           : (4070767:241:144)
    Start time    : Jul 29 2014  2:16:35:867PM
    SID           : 0x0
    DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

If I look at the table 'syslockinfo' with my database I can see this:

```
                                                   rsc_text                         rsc_bin                            rsc_valblk                         rsc_dbid rsc_indid rsc_objid   rsc_type rsc_flag req_mode req_status req_refcnt req_cryrefcnt req_lifetime req_spid    req_ecid    req_ownertype req_transactionID    req_transactionUOW
-------------------------------- ---------------------------------- ---------------------------------- -------- --------- ----------- -------- -------- -------- ---------- ---------- ------------- ------------ ----------- ----------- ------------- -------------------- ------------------------------------
                             0x0000000000000000000000001E000200 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 30       0         0           2        0        3        1          1          0             0            252         0           4             0                    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
                             0x0000000000000000000000001E000200 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 30       0         0           2        0        3        1          1          0             0            -2          0           4             0                    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

(2 row(s) affected)

Ok, it's not very readable. What I want to show there is an empty UOW guid so I cannot kill it with the Guid.

How can I solve this problem? What information do you need more?

EDIT:
I also restored the database on SQL Server 2012 and the bug is not present there either. So it only fails on SQL Server 2008 R2.